# Select substring "_id" in string using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I need help with regular expressions. I need to select "_id" and replace it with "_ID", but don't know how to do it exactly right. 
Example string: "test_id" must be as "test_ID", but "test_identification_number" must not be "test_IDentification_number".

Currently I have such regex: /(?:_id$|*id*)/, but it won't work, because it cannot replace `_id` with `_ID` and `_id_` with `_ID_`.

Thanks.

**Edit: I use PHP for it.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Have a look, does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/yA1vI6/1) match correct `id`s? Try [`preg_replace('/_id(?![\p{L}\d])/', "_ID", $str);`](http://ideone.com/J4vEnx).

Comment: You need to be more specific about the exceptions when you don't want _id to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this pattern:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=_)id(\b|_)/', 'ID$1', $string);
```

## [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jW3yJ3/1)

How it works:

- `(?<=_)`: positive lookbehind: The rest of the pattern will only match if it's preceded by an underscore. The underscore itself is not captured (ie not replaced)
- `id`: String literal -> matches *id*, obviously
- `(\b|_)`: grouping match for either a word-boundary (`\b`), or an underscore. This grouping is required, because a positive lookahead like `(?:\b|_)` will capture the trailing underscore (so you'd have to replace it with `'ID$1'`, but that will fail if the lookahead matches a word boundary ([see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hL8zS3/1))

Comment: I don't know why you need the positive lookbehind. Why don't you just include the underscore in the match, and then you add it again in the replacement? Wouldn't it be more efficient?

Comment: Hard to say. Perl's regexes (on which PCRE is based), can actually outperform standard capturing matches with lookaround assertions, but I don't know if that holds true for PHP. As always: it depends, and in this case, whichever pattern you use, the difference would be marginal (if any). I'd classify this kind of thing under Micro-optimization

Comment: It may be more or less efficient, and the difference after all is surely marginal. But you have to agree that adding an unnecessary lookbehind only adds to its unreadability and obfuscation. As if regex per se were not obfuscated enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word boundary qualifier : `\b` will only match at the start of the string, the end of the string or if the previous or following character isn't a word character.

so `_id\b` should only match words ending in `_id`, and not `_identifier`.

Answer (score 0):

[My solution](https://regex101.com/r/yN4mC7/1)

Search string:
`/(?<=_)id\b/g`

Replace string:
`ID`

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace to make substitutions based on regex.

```
$string_modified = preg_replace('/_id(\b|_)/','_ID$1',$string);
```

Comment: That's why he has to be more specific about the string he wants to replace.

Comment: He's perfectly clear about things: `test_id` should become `test_ID`, `test_identifaction_number` shouldn't change, but `test_id_number` should become `test_ID_number`.

Comment: Yes, until he decides that there is another exception that doesn't comply with your fancy lookbehind expression.

Comment: If the lookbehind fails, then a litteral `_` match would fail, too. PS: `$stringModified = preg_replace($pattern, $repl, $string);`, that echo shouldn't be there